# Property values missing in model when passed from controller action to view in ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a asp.net web app that displays a list of models in a table into a partial view. In the controller, all the properties in the models of the model list are populated and looking ok. The problem comes when I try to display these on the partial view, only description is populated, no id, no image string... I can't figure out what is going on

My data model DataModelDto:

```
namespace aspnet_client.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The DataModel data transfer object class.
    /// </summary>
    public class DataModelDto
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The identifier.
        /// </value>
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the description.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The description.
        /// </value>
        public string Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The image.
        /// </value>
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my controller action:

```
using aspnet_client.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace aspnet_client.Controllers
{
    public class RecordsController : Controller
    {
        public RecordsController()
        {
        }

        // GET: Records
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult _Records(List<DataModelDto> records)
        {
            if (records != null)
            {
                return PartialView(records);
            }

            else return null;          
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my partial view:

```
    @model List<aspnet_client.Models.DataModelDto>

<h2>Registros actualizados en tiempo real</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
            <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var record in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@record.Id</td>
                <td>@record.Description</td>
                <td>@record.Image</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am calling records partial view from a websocket service class (maybe not best practice though...), so when some data is updated in the server, this controller action will receive the updated model:

```
using aspnet_client.Controllers;
using aspnet_client.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace aspnet_client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The WebSocketService class
    /// </summary>
    public class WebSocketService
    {
        public RecordsController controller = new RecordsController();

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WebSocketService"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public WebSocketService()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the connection with the server.
        /// </summary>
        public void StartConnection()
        {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:4649/service");

            var records = new List<DataModelDto>();

            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message received in the client side: " + e.Data);
                records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataModelDto>>(e.Data);

                controller._Records(records);
            };

            ws.Connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated, this is such a mistery to me!

Comment: Your controller is not passing values, it's receiving them. How are you calling `_Records`?

Comment: Hi @GSerg I have updated my post, I call it from a service, but that shouldn't be the issue as the data is passed correctly to the controller action, all the props populated, feels like they're getting lost on their way from the controller to the view for some reason

Comment: That `controller._Records(records);` has no effect. It returns an `ActionResult` that is then discarded. If you meant to replace a part of an already rendered page, then that is done with javascript. But you cannot be doing that either because that `new RecordsController();` creates a bogus controller instance not related to any request processing pipelines, so it's not really clear [what](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) you wanted to do and why.

Comment: I did not get to the refreshing bit with javascript just yet, that'll be my next step, I'm just trying to print out the values for now, the question here is why only one of the properties is being populated and the others don't

Comment: You are returning `PartialView(records)` to the handler of `ws.OnMessage`. That handler then discards what you have returned. It could not do anything else with it really, because what is returned from `PartialView(records)` is the *intention* to render a view, not the rendered view itself. But even if it was a rendered view, where would you then send it?

Comment: `one of the properties is being populated and the others don't` - none of them are being populated. The entire result is discarded. Apparently you have an initial page from which you make a properly executed call to `_Records`, such as `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Records", initial_data)};`. That renders fine because that's how it's supposed to be. Your updates via `ws.OnMessage` then do absolutely nothing.

Comment: I got the description for all of them printed out in the recordsView so that property is in fact populated in all the models of the list, the other props comes in as Null in the view. Not too sure how I could refactor this to get this to work.

Comment: Like I said, you use javascript that calls `ActionResult _Records()` and uses the returned view to replace a part of the page. `_Records()`, in turn, should then retrieve the data from your service rather than expect to be given it.